# Service gunicorn not starting code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to configure a gunicorn service on an Red hat EC2 vm of amazon.

I created the sercvice file, but when I run it and check the status it tells me that it failed:

```
[Unit]  

Description=Gunicorn instance for a simple hello world app 

After=network.target

[Service] 

User=ec2-user

Group=nginx

WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/webserverflask 

Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/webserverflask/venv/bin" 

ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/webserverflask/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3
--bind unix:webserverflask.sock -m 007 wsgi 

Restart=always


[Install] 

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error message:

> ● webserver.service - Gunicorn instance for a simple hello world app
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webserver.service; enabled; vendor
> preset: disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed
> 2022-07-06 19:31:08 UTC; 20h ago  Main PID: 25957 (code=exited,
> status=203/EXEC)
>
> Jul 06 19:31:08 ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]:
> webserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
> Jul 06 19:31:08 ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]:
> webserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Jul 06 19:31:08
> ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]: webserver.service: Service
> RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart. Jul 06 19:31:08
> ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]: webserver.service: Scheduled
> restart job, restart counter is at 5. Jul 06 19:31:08
> ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Gunicorn instance for
> a simple hello world app. Jul 06 19:31:08 ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal
> systemd[1]: webserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly. Jul
> 06 19:31:08 ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]:
> webserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Jul 06 19:31:08
> ip-172-31-95-13.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn
> instance for a simple hello world app.

and here is my wsgi:

```
from app import app as application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.
If anyone had the same issue while trying to deploy a flask gunicorn using the tutorials on internet, here is my answer:

The problem was that the gunicorn file wasn't accessible, I still don't know why but I managed to fix the issue by moving gunicorn to **/usr/local/bin/gunicorn**

So my service file look like this now:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for a simple hello world app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=nginx
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --chdir /home/ec2-user --bind unix                                                                                 :webserverflask.sock -m 007 webserverflask.wsgi


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: How did you move it? Literally took the whole gunicorn from your bin in the environment and applied "mv"?

Comment: Rather copy it instead of moving it completely


```sudo cp env/bin/gunicorn /usr/local/bin/```

Answer (score 0):

I would start debugging by trying to run the ExecStart command manually, and see if that works (or what error you get):

```
$ cd /home/ec2-user/webserverflask
$ /home/ec2-user/webserverflask/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:webserverflask.sock -m 007 wsgi
```